# Attempting to select a field for username and password using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to figure out how to select an ID in a website that has a username and password using selenium so that I can login using a python script. The problem is the fields on the website don't seem to have IDs for their username and password fields in the HTML code and I'm not really sure as to how to get the fields I need.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

link = "https://logistics.vendini.com/"
login = "e-mail"
password = "pass"

chromedriver = "D:\Downloads\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(link)

username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control')
print(username)
```

I tried this just to see if finding it by class would work but all I get is the webpage opening and then I get this error

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64343/devtools/browser/8a74989c-0f07-442c-ba50-077d3ec005bc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/marko/Programming/RavensHouseCup/webscrape.py", line 13, in <module>
    username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control')
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".form-control"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

If you go to the website that is in the link variable and inspect the email address and password fields is there something I'm missing as to how I'd be able to access them?

So I added an explicit wait of 10 seconds which seems to allow me to input the email, but for some reason the password isn't working. The code I'm using is as follows

```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/input"))
    )

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/input")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/input")
username.send_keys(login)
password.send_keys(password)
```

The e-mail gets entered correctly, but the password is giving me an error saying

```
File "d:/marko/Programming/RavensHouseCup/webscrape.py", line 24, in <module>
    password.send_keys(password)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

Comment: To add some more information, I've gone into the inspect elements of the field I'm trying to use, right clicked it and copied the XPath and tried to use this line "username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/input")" and I'm still getting a very similar error to before, "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)"

Answer (score 0):

When the page first loads the element is not present, there appears to be some JS that loads the form. You need to [wait for the element to be present](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'form-control')))
print(username)
```

Comment: Okay so I actually just added an implicit wait of 10 seconds, which probably isn't the best solution since if it ever takes longer than 10 seconds it wont work, but I just wanted to test it and it actually manages to input the email with this code "driver.get(link)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/input")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/input")
username.send_keys(login)
password.send_keys(password)"

Answer (score 0):

I am the stupidest coder alive. I realized my mistake, I had 2 different variables both named password, sorry everyone, I'm a moron. I changed the actual password to the website to be password2 and it all works!